# Disabled controls in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, internet-explorer, firefox

First of all in my custom webpage project, i use a master-page.

What drives me nuts, is that hyperlinks (2 of 5 in a child page) seem to be disabled while debugging with firefox (V3.5.5).

I face the same problem with a radio-button-list which exists within an asp wizard control.
It seems to be disabled, (Does not accept focus).

What i cannot figure out why this happens only in firefox and not in I.E.

**UPDATE:** This one works both in firefox and IE

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSh" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" Text="Update your personal"></asp:Label>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperProfile" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
                Font-Size="8pt" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#FF6D06" 
                NavigateUrl="~/ClientCenter/MyAccount.aspx">Profile</asp:HyperLink>
```

and this one works only in I.E.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperUpdateSuscription" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
                Font-Size="8pt" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#FF6D06" 
                NavigateUrl="~/ClientCenter/PlaceOrder.aspx">Update</asp:HyperLink>
        <asp:Label ID="lblShmeio9" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" 
                ForeColor="White" 
                Text="your subscription"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the markup that works in IE, but not in Firefox?  That would help determine the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i should use first http://validator.w3.org/

A div tag was overlapping the specific objects (hyperlinks - radio-button-list) and that's why, they seemed to be disabled